# Hide site contents such as lists and tasks

Tags: harmon.ie

We are evaluating the Outlook plugin and it works pretty good except for the fact that it shows all the site contents when connecting to a site. We want users to give the ability to upload mails/attachments to a document library, but when they open the side bar, they see all the document libraries and also all the lists, tasks, links, workflow tasks, etc etc..

Is it possible to hide them? So that users only see document libraries? I think they will get confused seeing all those lists & task lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, harmon.ie includes lists/libraries with following templates IDs

```
GenericList = 100,
DocumentLibrary = 101,
Links = 103,
Announcements = 104,
Contacts = 105,
Tasks = 107,
PictureLibrary = 109,
TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy = 171,
MySiteDocumentLibrary = 700,
IssueTracking = 1100
```

you can set the "ExcludedLibraryTemplates" key to exclude the template IDs of other list types as follows

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\ExcludedLibraryTemplates]
@="100,103,104,105,107,171,1100"
```

More details about available configuration options are found in https://harmon.ie/provision-harmonie-outlook-all-users

Comment: Maksim, thank you for the clarification! Can this also be done on the free version? I cannot find the 'ExcludedLibraryTemplates' key.

Comment: Nevermind, I've created the key and it works perfect! Thank you!